# How to structure relationships in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two sets of data in the same collection in cosmos, one are 'posts' and the other are 'users', they are linked by the posts users create.

Currently my structure is as follows;

```
// user document
{
id: 123,
postIds: ['id1','id2']
}

// post document
{
id: 'id1',
ownerId: 123
}
{
id: 'id2',
ownerId: 123
}
```

My main issue with this setup is the fungible nature of it, code has to enforce the link and if there's a bug data will very easily be lost with no clear way to recover it.

I'm also concerned about performance, if a user has 10,000 posts that's 10,000 lookups I'll have to do to resolve all the posts..

Is this the correct method for modelling entity relationships?

Comment: You are trying to use Cosmos DB in a way that it is not meant to be used like. CosmosDB is not a relational database and there are no constraints when it comes to object modelling. You should design your Cosmos collections in a way that you never have to do a cross partition query. This current design look like it would need that.

Comment: So then all the post objects would exist directly on the user? But then if I want to show all posts made by everyone I would have to query every user and get the posts out of them?

Comment: But then what if posts can be ‘liked’ by any user, how is that modelled? The id of the voting user would be stored against the post inside the owner user? Then to get all the likes a user has made ill have to query users... is that how it’s supposed to work?

Comment: It comes down to your partitioning strategy and being strict with who can modify your database. I will write a detailed answer.

Comment: @NickChapsas - there's really no "right" answer to be had, here. So many ways to model this data, each with upsides and downsides. There are options for mixing normalized (relational) ids (with arrays?) with denormalized data for fast display (e.g. snippet of most recent post being embedded in user doc, array of subdocs w/id+short descrip?). Same thing with storing 'likes'. And we have no information regarding how this data will be used/displayed, read- vs write-heavy workloads, on and on. It's a *terrific* discussion to have, but... it doesn't really fit here, given its very broad nature.

Comment: @NickChapsas I'm just a bit confused about how to make data relate to one another, I understand it's a none-relational database so does that mean we just duplicate data wherever we might need to access it from? In which case how do we keep the data in sync? How can i not query cross partition when one type of data invariably refers to another from a different partition? If cross partition should never happen why even have partitions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As said by David, it's a long discussion but it is a very common one so, since I have on hour or so of "free" time, I'm more than glad to try to answer it, once for all, hopefully.

**WHY NORMALIZE?**

First thing I notice in your post: you are looking for some level of referential integrity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) which is something that is needed when you decompose a bigger object into its constituent pieces. Also called normalization.

While this is normally done in a relational database, it is now also becoming popular in non-relational database since it helps a lot to avoid data duplication which usually creates more problem than what it solves.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models

But do you really need it? Since you have chosen to use JSON document database, you should leverage the fact that it's able to store the entire document and then just store the document ALONG WITH all the owner data: name, surname, or all the other data you have about the user who created the document. Yes, I’m saying that you may want to evaluate not to have post and user, but just posts, with user info inside it.This may be actually very correct, as you will be sure to get the EXACT data for the user existing at the moment of post creation. Say for example I create a post and I have biography "X". I then update my biography to "Y" and create a new post. The two post will have different author biographies and this is just right, as they have exactly captured reality.

Of course you may want to also display a biography in an author page. In this case you'll have a problem. Which one you'll use? Probably the last one.

If all authors, in order to exist in your system, MUST have blog post published, that may well be enough. But maybe you want to have an author write its biography and being listed in your system, even before he writes a blog post.

In such case you need to NORMALIZE the model and create a new document type, just for authors. If this is your case, then, you also need to figure out how to handler the situation described before. When the author will update its own biography, will you just update the author document, or create a new one? If you create a new one, so that you can keep track of all changes, will you also update all the previous post so that they will reference the new document, or not?

As you can see the answer is complex, and REALLY depends on what kind of information you want to capture from the real world.

So, first of all, figure out if you really need to keep posts and users separated.

**CONSISTENCY**

Let’s assume that you really want to have posts and users kept in separate documents, and thus you normalize your model. In this case, keep in mind that Cosmos DB (but NoSQL in general) databases DO NOT OFFER any kind of native support to enforce referential integrity, so you are pretty much on your own. Indexes can help, of course, so you may want to index the ownerId property, so that before deleting an author, for example, you can efficiently check if there are any blog post done by him/her that will remain orphans otherwise.
Another option is to manually create and keep updated ANOTHER document that, for each author, keeps track of the blog posts he/she has written. With this approach you can just look at this document to understand which blog posts belong to an author. You can try to keep this document automatically updated using triggers, or do it in your application. *Just keep in mind, that when you normalize, in a NoSQL database, keep data consistent is YOUR responsibility. This is exactly the opposite of a relational database, where your responsibility is to keep data consistent when you de-normalize it.*

**PERFORMANCES**

Performance COULD be an issue, but you don't usually model in order to support performances in first place. You model in order to make sure your model can represent and store the information you need from the real world and then you optimize it in order to have decent performance with the database you have chose to use. As different database will have different constraints, the model will then be adapted to deal with that constraints. This is nothing more and nothing less that the good old “logical” vs “physical” modeling discussion.

In Cosmos DB case, you should not have queries that go cross-partition as they are more expensive.

Unfortunately partitioning is something you chose once and for all, so you really need to have clear in your mind what are the most common use case you want to support at best. If the majority of your queries are done on per author basis, I would partition per author.

Now, while this may seems a clever choice, it will be only if you have A LOT of authors. If you have only one, for example, all data and queries will go into just one partition, limiting A LOT your performance. Remember, in fact, that Cosmos DB RU are split among all the available partitions: with 10.000 RU, for example, you usually get 5 partitions, which means that all your values will be spread across 5  partitions. Each partition will have a top limit of 2000 RU. If all your queries use just one partition, your real maximum performance is that 2000 and not 10000 RUs.

I really hope this help you to start to figure out the answer. And I really hope this help to foster and grow a discussion (how to model for a document database) that I think it is really due and mature now.